# Small trouble in finding Laplace Transform of $\sqrt{t}$ without using Gamma function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, laplace-transform

### We know that :

### $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ t^{\frac{1}{2}} \right \}=\frac{\Gamma (\frac{1}{2}+1)}{S^{\frac{1}{2}+1}}=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }/2}{S^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

### I'm trying to prove that without using the Gamma function .

### $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \} = \mathcal{L} \left \{ t\frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \right \} = -\frac{d}{ds}(\mathcal{L} \left \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \right \})\Rightarrow (1)$$

### Now I find $\mathcal{L} \left \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \right \}$ using the property :

### $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ {f}'(t) \right \} = s \mathcal{L} \left \{ f(t) \right \}-f(0)$$

### by putting $$f(t)=\sqrt{t} \Rightarrow {f}'(t)=\frac{1/2}{\sqrt{t}}$$

### $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ \frac{1/2}{\sqrt{t}} \right \} = s \mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \}- \sqrt{0} \Rightarrow 2\mathcal{L} \left \{ \frac{1/2}{\sqrt{t}} \right \} = 2s \mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \}$$

### $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} \right \} = 2s\mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \} \Rightarrow (2)$$ , substituting from (2) in (1) :

### $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \} = -\frac{d}{ds}(2S\mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \} )$$

### Let : $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \}= h(s)$$ , then :

### $$h = -\frac{d}{ds}(2Sh ) \Rightarrow h = -2h -2S {h}'$$

### $$\Rightarrow 2S{h}'+3h=0 \Rightarrow {h}'+\frac{3}{2S}h=0$$

### The integrating factor is :

### $$e^{\int \frac{3}{2S}ds} = e^{\frac{3}{2}ln(S)}=S^{\frac{3}{2}}$$

### $${(S^{\frac{3}{2}}h)}'=0 \Rightarrow S^{\frac{3}{2}}h = C \Rightarrow h(s)=\frac{C}{S^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

### Finally : back substitute

### $$\mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \} = h(s) \Rightarrow \mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \} = h(s) \Rightarrow \mathcal{L} \left \{ \sqrt{t} \right \} = \frac{C}{S^{\frac{3}{2}}}$$

### Here is the trouble how can I prove that $C = \sqrt{\pi }/2$ , or what is the wrong in the steps above ?

Comment: The Laplace transform of $\sqrt{t}$ is related to $\Gamma(3/2)$ in a intrinsic way, since $\mathcal{L}(\sqrt{t})(s) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\sqrt{t} e^{-st}\,dt=\frac{1}{s\sqrt{s}}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sqrt{u}e^{-u}\,du$ by the very definition of Laplace transform.

Comment: On the other hand, if you know the value of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}e^{-u^2}\,du$ you also know the value of $\int_{0}^{+\infty}\sqrt{u}e^{-u}\,du$ by integration by parts and straightforward substitutions.

Comment: I do note that the value of $f'(0)$ does not exist nor the value of the transform at $s=0$. So the differential equation vanishes for any useful/trivial notable value. You'll likely have to use a trick like the ones mentioned above.

Answer (score 1):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \sqrt t e^{-st}\,dt&\overbrace{=}^{t\mapsto t^2}2\int_0^\infty t^2e^{-st^2}\,dt\\\\
&=-2\frac{d}{ds}\int_0^\infty e^{-st^2}\,dt\\\\
&=-2\frac{d}{ds}\left(\frac1{\sqrt s}\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2}\right)\\\\
&=\frac{\sqrt\pi}{2s^{3/2}}
\end{align}$$